# How to debug "Response Code 500 Internal server error" in J-Meter 4.0?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am getting "Response code 500 - Internal Server Error" for a performance test run in Apache J-Meter 4.0 for a recording of a simple test done over VPN. I am new to this tool and want to know how I can investigate this. As reference, I am mentioning the sampler result error that I am getting.

```
Sampler Result:

Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-06-11 13:21:56 IST
Load time: 1941
Connect Time: 1700
Latency: 1941
Size in bytes: 2301
Sent bytes:2145
Headers size in bytes: 594
Body size in bytes: 1707
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Mon, 11 Jun 2018 07:51:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1707
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: AWSALB=ZS1nnfJyJ+Wk5NEu/FmWGmiRWfEQPnfiywAN8b8f8De6AjOYDrh0nWRVVcsQeBanayjPnpp1IxhjK34EipQB4m/lsAZgdKJ4mgUDDS+Yep8atzWucMNdYTw0oIdB; Expires=Mon, 18 Jun 2018 07:51:58 GMT; Path=/
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
Vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: Express


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8
```

Comment: (Note: please do not ask for one-on-one support here, or a private telephone/VOIP call - this platform is for solving problems in public in a way to help future readers. If you need private paid support, I can make some suggestions on where else to look.)

Comment: A 500 error is a problem inside the application you are testing. It is not very specific, and thus you will need to examine the logs of the SUT to discover what the problem is. The SUT does have the option of rendering a more specific error, but it has chosen to give you "Internal Server Error", which is the least informative error message possible (in computer terms it is a statement of the obvious). Do you have access to the project so you can examine its logs?

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases you will not be able to successfully replay recorded scenario without modifications.

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan
2. Detect all dynamic parameters and perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)
3. Also looking into `AWSALB` cookie my expectation is that your application under test "hides" behind [Amazon Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) so make sure to add [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan.

If you still experience problems you can try catching the requests which is being sent by JMeter and by the real browser using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) - the requests should be **exactly** the same (apart from dynamic parameters mentioned in point 2).